# Running a java program with multiple jar files and classes

Tags: java, jar, javac

I am compiling a program with multiple jar files (inside the lib folder) and classes (inside the src/com folder) with:

```
javac -classpath lib/\* src/com/*.java
```

I typed this to run the program:

```
java -cp lib/\* src/com/okc
```

But it doesn't work. Instead, I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.com.okc
```

okc.java is the class containing the main method. How can I run a java program with multiple jar files and classes?

Comment: Have you tried those tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/3318377)?

Comment: Have you tried `java -cp lib\*.jar;. com.okc`?

Answer (score 2):

A Java class file is not just the file itself.  The directory structure which represents a class's package is *part of the class file.*  Your classpath needs to point to the directory which is the parent of the topmost package directory.

Assuming your class is declared with `package com;`, the topmost package directory is `com`.  So you need the *parent* of `com` in your classpath:

```
java -classpath src:lib/\* com.okc
```

If your class does not contain any `package` statement, and you just happened to put it in a `com` directory, then it belongs to the null package, whose parent directory is `com` itself:

```
java -classpath src/com:lib/\* okc
```

An additional note:  It is Java convention to have class names, and their respective file names, start with an uppercase letter.  One reason is that it makes class names easy to distinguish from package components.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
java -cp ../lib/\* com.okc
```

from the src directory (not sure...)

Comment: Nope :( still getting Error: Could not find or load main class

Comment: are you executing from the src directory?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your current directory has your lib/ :

java -cp lib src.com.okc

Comment: Still getting the error Error: Could not find or load main class :/